# Keep Observable alive in Angular

Tags: angular, observable

I have a function that I want to convert into an Observable function. It wasn't designed originally to be the one, so I am just trying adapting it. Here is how it looks with my changes:

```
private func1(param): Observable<any> {
   const httpClientRequest = this.anotherFunc(params).subscribe((value: any) => {
      // logic that should return a flag of its completion
      return of(value);
   }
   return NEVER.pipe(startWith(7));
}
```

Subscriber:

```
 this.func1(param).subscribe(
     (value: any) => {
           console.log(value);
      }
 );
```

My expectation was because of NEVER operator I would see two entries in the Console, but I only see 7.
Is it possible to achieve what I am trying to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> My expectation was because of NEVER operator I would see two entries in the Console, but I only see 7

`NEVER` never emits :-)  Adding `startWith` forces an emission of `7`, which is what you are seeing.  You are essentially returning an observable, that has nothing to do with your `anotherFunc()` call.

You can simply return the result of your function call, if you just need `Observable`:

```js
private func1(param): Observable<any> {  // return type is `Observable<whatever anotherFunc() returns>`
   return this.anotherFunc(params);
}
```

Notice, there's no `subscribe()` above.  Consumers of the function would subscribe:

```js
 this.func1(param).subscribe(
     (value: any) => {
           console.log(value);
      }
 );
```

> // logic that should return a flag of its completion

I'm not sure if you meant you just want to return boolean and not the response value, but you could achieve that like this:

```js
private func1(param): Observable<boolean> { 
   return this.anotherFunc(params).pipe(
      mapTo(true)
   );
}
```

Comment: As far as "keeping the observable alive": what exactly do you mean?  Do you not want a subscription to `func1` to complete?

Comment: I cannot return anotherFunc because of the way it's been constructed. That's why I have to have to returns: one is the last statement in the function, another when processing really completes. Also if I return anotherFunc  then the return type is not matching what :Observable <any> expects.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to return.  When you subscribe to `func1` what data do you want to receive?

Comment: I want to return of(value); but this.func1 only gets results of this: return NEVER.pipe(startWith(7));

Comment: `of(value)` is the result from `anotherFunc`!!!  If you simply don't subscribe, you don't need `of`.  Sorry, I'm not clear on why this solution isn't working for you.  Can you explain further or create a little [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com)

Comment: Maybe you got this going by now, but I was just re-reading and wondered if in your example above, are you trying to emit a static value, then the result of your http call?

Comment: The static value is just to see what's been returned. What really was needed is the result of http call.